# If else statement to pass image size on to surrounding div

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, dimension

On my site all images within the main content are wrapped into a div container like this:

```
<div class="imagecontainer">
  <img src="image.jpg" width="300" />
</div>
```

I need to add the images width to its surrounding div. This works using:

```
$('.imagecontainer').each(function() {
  $(this).width( $(this).find('img').attr('width') );
});
```

BUT only, if the image has a width attribute. If I use the width() element instead of attr('width') than all images without a width attribute display a width of 0.

I also tried a couple of if-else statement to check:

1. If the image has a width attribute than add this to its surrounding div.
2. Else use the images displayed width and add this to its surrounding div.

But without success.

Isnt there a way to grab the images displayed size and add it to its surrounding div?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The container div will have the same width as the image anyway

Comment: @OneTrickPony - Why would you say that? Here's a fiddle to disprove you: http://jsfiddle.net/MeKWW/

Comment: But there's no text in the markup from this question. And even if it had text, why would he want to resize a DIV with text and an image, to the width of the image? It makes no sense

Comment: @OneTrickPony - The OP (correctly) only included the code relevant to the question. As for resizing the `div` to the image width; here's the fiddle again: http://jsfiddle.net/MeKWW/1/

Comment: @One Trick Pony - I need a div around the img for an image hover mask and the mask has to have the same dimensions as the image. Next time I clarify this in my original posting. Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.width()` *is* the right way to do it, but you have to wait for the window to `load`, so that when you run the code the images have already been loaded:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    $('.imagecontainer').each(function() {
        $(this).width( $(this).find('img').width() );
    });
});
```

You should probably cache that `$(this)` object.

Comment: Yes, that works like a charme. I read about using onload, but had no idea how to implement it.